# T-Sql, How to get these results?

Tags: t-sql

This query

```
      SELECT PA.refPatient_id
            ,MAX(PA.datee) AS datee
            ,PR.temporary,PA.statue

        FROM PatientClinicActs AS PA
            ,PatientStatueReasons AS PR

       WHERE PA.refClinic_id = 25 
         AND PA.refreason_id = PR.reason_id

    GROUP BY PA.refPatient_id,PA.statue,PR.temporary
```

returns these results:

```
refPatient_id datee                 temporary statue
----------- ----------------------- ------ -----
14706       2008-12-01 11:01:00     1      0
14707       2009-05-18 16:21:00     1      0
14708       2009-07-15 09:46:00     1      0
14708       2009-07-29 16:12:00     1      0
14716       2009-11-09 12:29:00     0      0
14716       2009-09-01 11:15:00     1      0
14716       2009-09-29 16:44:00     1      1
```

But i want to have these results:

```
refPatient_id datee                   temporary statue
----------- ----------------------- ------ -----
14706       2008-12-01 11:01:00     1      0
14707       2009-05-18 16:21:00     1      0
14708       2009-07-29 16:12:00     1      0
14716       2009-11-09 12:29:00     0      0
```

What is the difference ? => I have newest row for every refPatient_id in these results.
What should i run to get these results?

Comment: You want to get the latest for a given refPatient_Id? Do a rank() over and select where rank == 1 should work

Comment: I want to get the latest row for each refPatient_id. Would you please write an example with rank?

Comment: Your 14708 results: they look wrong in 1st result set. You should not get that result with that query with that grouping

Comment: ok. Do you have any advice? Or should i write loop with cursor?

Comment: @uzay95: advice = post schema and code

Comment: @uzay95: advice = post SQL server edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT  PA.refPatient_id,
        PA.datee,
        PR.temporary,
        PA.statue
FROM    PatientClinicActs AS PA INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PA.refPatient_id,
                    MAX(PA.datee) AS datee
            FROM    PatientClinicActs AS PA
            WHERE   PA.refClinic_id = 25          
            GROUP BY PA.refPatient_id,PA.statue,PA.datee,
        ) AS MaxDates ON PA.refPatient_id = MaxDates.refPatient_id AND PA.datee = MaxDates.datee INNER JOIN
        PatientStatueReasons AS PR ON PA.refreason_id = PR.reason_id
```

You need to get the max date per patient first, then join to that.

Comment: It still has more than one row for some patients.

Comment: Tha might be due to either the MAX date occuring more than once in PatientClinicActs or the link to PatientStatueReasons containing more than one entry for a patient, in which case you must decide how to choose the appropriate record. What will make it the one you need?

Comment: I voted you down because I was misreading sth... Cannot undo it apparently, so I voted you up on 'Retrieving rows with the highest value'for fairness

Comment: Ok. if i retrive refPatient_id, refReason_id and datee, i could have more than 1 actions for some patients. Because they might be passive (statue=0) and then active(statue=1) with some reasons.

Comment: Then change it to select only the statue you require 0 or 1

Comment: Good, but i need to know what this patient did (leave/come) with his/her last movement...

Comment: Provide the table structure you have and some data, and that will make things easier.

Comment: @Peter: You can't reverse a downvote until after the answer has been editted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a cross join

```
FROM PatientClinicActs AS PA
                ,PatientStatueReasons AS PR
```

can you try with inner join

```
FROM PatientClinicActs AS PA

INNER JOIN PatientStatueReasons AS PR 

ON PA.refreason_id = PR.reason_id

WHERE PA.refClinic_id = 25
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I have learnt a lot from you and is still learning. Your comments are always valuable to me. Thanks again

Comment: It's not a cross join - it's an inner join using non ANSI JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of cases, there is another way to get the *latest* record by using [SQL Server Ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).

I have used [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) for my answer, but you can use [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), instead for your particular problem.
(**note**: code below is not tested.  If you were to provide schema for tables, I would have tested with sample data)

```
;with RankedResult as (
    SELECT  
    PA.refPatient_id
    , PA.datee
    , PR.temporary,
    , PA.statue
    --; Last datee has the lowest rank value of 1,
    , dense_rank() over 
        (partition by PA.refPatient_id order by PA.datee desc) as [Rank]
    FROM    PatientClinicActs AS PA
            join PatientStatueReasons AS PR on PA.refreason_id = PR.reason_id
    WHERE   PA.refClinic_id = 25 
)
select  distinct *
from    RankedResult
--; Get only the last result.
where   [Rank] = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Take the PA.datee out of the group by clause